# J: About optimal applying of sequence of filters to a list

Tags: optimization, filter, sequence, j

Let ***{f(i)}, i = 1,...,n*** be a sequence of filters (each item of a list is mapped to a boolean value) with a property: *if* **f(i) = 1** *for some item of a list, then every* **f(j) = 1** *for* **j > i** *and the same item*. Very simple example:

```
   [ t =: i.5   NB. sample data
0 1 2 3 4

   f1 =: 2&>           NB. is greater than 2
   f2 =: 2&> +. 0=2&|  NB. is greater than 2 OR even

   (f1 ,: f2) t
1 1 0 0 0
1 1 1 0 1

   (#~ f1 +. f2) t
0 1 2 4
```

Obviously there is no need to apply `f2` to first 2 items of `t` (that has been already accepted by `f1`).

**Question**: How to avoid applying **f(j)** to items that was accepted by **f(i)** for **j > i** ?

**My naive implementation**

`I. -. f1 t` - indices of those items that are not accepted by f1. So why not select them, apply `f2` and amend? I think that it's a wrong way, because this approach uses a lot of memory, right?

```
   t #~ (f1 t) (I. -. f1 t)}~ f2 (I. -. f1 t) { t
0 1 2 4
```

And it's harder to code for many filters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While it is possible to avoid computation in the manner you seek here, doing so tends to run "against the grain" of J. Notably, doing so is likely to increase the time and space requirements.

One technique would be to use the result of `f1` to filter the argument to `f2` and then expand the result of `f2` to align with the result of `f1`. This will involve creating a new array in memory in order to have exactly the necessary values, plus a temporary result array, and also computation over that result to make it conform to the shape of the original argument. These things are not free.

Most importantly, this sort of micro-management involves a move away from what J programmers call array-thinking. Solutions that involve working with nouns "as a whole" (and as conforming rectangles) are often amenable to concise expression in J.

For certain types of calculation on certain types of data the class of problem you have posed may well be important. In such cases it could be worth contriving some technique for communicating partial results and selectively avoiding avoidable application of a verb. I'd guess Power (`^:`) would be useful in many such efforts. But these solutions would all be quite specific to circumstances where actual performance problems were appearing.

I take the risk of making the following claim: there is no *general* answer to your question because the generalities of J do not support fine-grained intervention. I suspect you have a solid understanding that J exhibits this bias. That bias is what makes the question you posed a technically difficult question.

Since the solutions to this problem will very often not run in less time, nor less memory, nor assist brevity of expression, nor functional clarity, "optimization" seems an unlikely label for them.

Comment: Thank you, @kaleidic for well-reasoned answer. I'm new to J so it's important to me to read about J paradigms in comparison to popular ones. I understand the paradigm "as a whole" now better, however I believe that the task I'm facing has a performance problem indeed. Shortly, I'll edit the question to formulate my task, but it's a bit intricate.

Comment: I have suspected that verb-power can be applied, but what have I concluded so far about `^:` is that a sentence `(f2^:(-.@:f1))"0 t` will apply f2 only for those items that are needed to be filtered, but the result is not a boolean list, thus it's an inefficient use of memory. I don't see another use of it for now.

Comment: Unfortunately, I found that I cannot formulate my problem, because it's a long story, and my question is not very important for it, nevertheless, I've learnt important things, and understood J a bit more. Thanks.